# How to Create a Default Login Page

Tags: joomla-3.4

This request is a little difficult to explain.

I have a page the requests a login to access the page. I have created a default username and password that potential customers can use to access the page. However, I think people aren't even bothered to enter the default username and password. Therefore, I would like to users to be able to click on the link to the page and automatically be logged in to access the page.

I thought that one solution might be to somehow configuring Joomla so the username and password is already entered so that when a user clicks on the link they're automatically taken to the page, but I dont know how to do that.

If someone could show me, or have any other suggestions, that would be great.

Comment: Hi Community, can I get some help with this please. I understand the way I have phrased the question might be a little confusing, but let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

**Joomla Autologin Extension**

There are free plugins available to do this at [textarea.it](http://www.textarea.it/en/joomla-free-extensions/joomla-autologin-extension.html) but the link is currently broken. Direct links to the plugins still seem to be working:

- [download plg_autologin.2.5.2.zip](http://www.textarea.it/images/extensions/plg_autologin.2.5.2.zip) Joomla! 2.5, 3.0 and 3.1 native
- [download plg_autologin.1.3.zip](http://www.textarea.it/images/extensions/plg_autologin.1.3.zip) Joomla! 1.5 native

**Allow Logins from customer IP Addresses**

Another option may be to install [Auto Login IP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/auto-login-ip) or [Regular Labs IP Login](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ip-login) (both free) or similar so authorised customers can login without entering credentials.

This is probably only practical for customers with static IP addresses so may not be suitable in your situation.

**Develop your own login page**

You can probably implement your own login page along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/a/4195116/1983389 to achieve similar functionality to the Joomla Autologin Extension above.

---

**Security Considerations**

Note: As per the Stack Overflow post, some of these methods are not a good idea from a security point of view and you should think carefully about the security implications before proceeding.

Comment: Neil, thanks. Going to try the plg_autologin. As regards, Auto Login IP, or NoNumber IP Login. You mentioned that customers would need a static ip address for this to work. Do you mean a static public IP Address?

Comment: To enable IP addresses, customers would need to tell you what IP address they are using. This will only work if they are regularly logging in from the same IP address. This might be possible in a work environment but users logging in from home or roaming may not always have the same IP address.

Comment: OK. I understand. Anyway, I have successfully installed plg_autologin 2.5.2. However, I can't find it when I do a search for it in plugin manager to enable it. I searched for it with name 'autologin', but nothing appeared. Any thoughts - I'm clearly a novice :-(

Comment: OK. It looks like the plugin name is "System - Autologin". You may need to amend the Default List Limit to "All" or advance to a subsequent page before you see it in the list.

Comment: OK. I found it. Going to try and get it to work. I hope you'll stick around :-)

Comment: Hi Neil, I'm still being asked to login first, before taking me to the required page :-(

Comment: Oh, I just realised this is access to the my whole Joomla site! I don't want that. Wow! that could be a disaster. I just want it so that users that click on a link in my site aren't asked for a username or password, or alternatively, I am able to already enter in the username and password so that users don't have to.

Comment: Users still have to supply a username and password and include this in the login url like this: `www.domain.com/index.php?user=admin&passw=xxxxx` so there is some level of security although this is not ideal.

Comment: I have inserted the following www.keylooplabs.com/index.php?user=guest&passw=password, however I just ended up at the home page of www.keylooplabs.com. Any other thoughts (administrator, please don't move this discussion to chat)

Comment: Have you enabled the plugin?

Comment: Neil, I think what I need is the ability to access an area in my website without having to login - my web designer called it 'User Area'

Comment: I disabled the 'System - AutoLogin', because everyone on the internet would be able to access my Joomla configuration files etc...

Comment: OK. You might need to modify your question or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few lines of jQuery to fill out the form. Just make sure the username/password you provide only gives limited access to your site.

```
(function($) { 
    $("#username").val("Guest");
    $("#password").val("guest123");
})(jQuery);
```

By adding this code to your page, the fields will be filled in with your login data. The user will still have to click the login button, though. If you also want to submit the form automatically, you can do something like this after line #3:

```
$(".login form").submit();
```

*(In order to add the script to your page, you can use an extension like [Sourcerer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer) or similar).*