# Admin login with url

Tags: login

Does anyone know how to login to Joomla administration using a URL?

Someting like:

http://myweb.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_login&task=login&username=user1&passwd=pass1

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this pose a big security risk?

Comment: This is a similar question to: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/14864/120

Answer (score 1):

With [IP Login from Regular Labs](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/iplogin) (ex-NoNumber!) you can log into you Joomla frontend and/administrator side automatically by IP address.

You can simply set up your IP address and a secret URL key in your user profile in the administrator.

After installing IP Login, you will have below settings in every user profile. So to set up IP Login for your user, go to the User Manager and click on your user account.

[image]

With above example, you will be able to automatically log in on IP address 123.456.789.123 with URL key mxx8hrv4.

The URL key needs to be put in the url as a 'query' variable, like:
`http://www.yourdomain.com?mxx8hrv4`

If the URL already contains a ?, you can prepend the key with an &, like:
`http://www.yourdomain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&mxx8hrv4`

*Security warning*

*Be aware that there is a small security risk. The risk is low, as the hacker will have to find out your IP address (and spoof it), know that you have set it up as auto-log-in IP address and somehow find out your secret URL key.*

Answer (score 1):

Initially it's not possible, because Joomla, com_users especially, checking security token.

You can create your custom plugins I believe, but there is no possibility by default.